# UL LI with Background Image in one row

Tags: html, css

I am debugging one tricky alignment problem. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/U2Wax/4/). The problem is that the Rating "Thumbs" Up & Down are present in a single image. I am using `background-position` to generate different images.

The visual looks is looking well, but I **need to show all four features in one line with background images along with them**.

Does anyone know how to fix it ?

Comment: Do you mean to have all the features aligned to the left, like a normal list, or do you mean to have all the features in one line, like a long sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Ok from what I think I understand you want to have your rating class in a seperate span to the actual text in the li.

```
<li><span class="rating up"></span>Courteous Staff</li>
```

Then set the span to `display: inline-block;` and you should get what I think you're after.

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/U2Wax/35/

You need to do a bit more work to get it aligned right but it will give you a good idea.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? You mean make them wider?

Comment: Courteous Staff, Waiting Area,Safe Location... needs to be in 1 line

Comment: Just change the width on ul.rating-features li. Eg: width: 16%;

Answer (score -1):

have you tried adding this css style?

```
white-space: nowrap;
```